# powershell list last log and insert body email

Tags: powershell

Hello i need to send the last .log and insert in $body with get-content

```
$Logpath = "D:\Script\"

$LastLog = Get-ChildItem $Logpath | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} | select-object Name -last 1

$fullpath = Write-Output $Logpath $LastLog

$body = Get-Content $fullpath | out-string

PS D:\Script\> Get-ChildItem $Logpath | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} | select-object Name -last 1

Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
test05.txt
```

$fullpath doesn't work and $body i don't know how put up..

thx 4 help im noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may help you:

```
$Logpath   = "D:\Script\"
$yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

# this will get you a FileInfo object of the latest log file
$LastLog = Get-ChildItem $Logpath -File | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $yesterday} | Select-Object -Last 1

# the FileInfo object has a 'FullName' property
Write-Host "Reading file '$($LastLog.FullName)'"

# to get the content as a single string, use the '-Raw' switch
$body = Get-Content $LastLog.FullName -Raw 

# to send this as email, have a look at the 'Send-MailMessage' cmdlet at
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6

#basic example on 'Send-MailMessage'
Send-MailMessage -To "someone@example.com" -From "me@example.com" -Subject "Log $($LastLog.Name)" -Body $body
```

Comment: About $LastLog command, doesn't work, i removed -File and now it's running.

About Write-Host: Reading file ' ' .. it's blank

and $body give nothing also

what can i do?

Comment: Are you using Powershell version less then 3.0 perhaps? In that case, `-File` won't work. Can you check if there actually are files in the `$LogPath` with a `LastWriteTime` newer that yesterday's date?